# The Sony Remote API, AvailableAPI List, does not show all the supported methods claimed by sony

Tags: sony-camera-api

I have successfully implemented the Sony Remote API in c# on windows. It works well with the QX10. However, I was asked to use the implementation with the DSC-HX90V and the ILCE-5000.

How do I put the HX90V and the ILCE-5000 in a mode that will allow me to use them the same way I use the QX10?

The SSID is not always broadcast.

The SSID will broadcast if I put the camera into the Smart Remote Embedded mode.

I can connect to the cameras and get the AvailableAPI List but that list does not contain the supported feature your "Supported API features for each compatible camera" table says it supports. That table is shown at https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

How do I put these cameras in a mode that supports the supported features?
If I can not, I would like to know that.

Answer (score 0):

The startRecMode function is not listed in the available api list of the QX10.

It is found in the short 7 element available api list of the DSC-HX90V and the ILCE-5000.

Once I call the startRecMode on the cameras I then need to get the available api list again.
The new available api list is the full list of functions.

All is well.